# Sequelize Error: Error: Dialect needs to be explicitly supplied as of v4.0.0

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, .env

While prepping an application for deployment, an error:

```
 Error: Dialect needs to be explicitly supplied as of v4.0.0
```

started popping up whenever i run npm run develop.  i'm using a .env file for my environmental variables.  The connection.js code is :

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
require('dotenv').config({path: '../.env'});

let sequelize;

if (process.env.JAWSDB_URL) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.JAWSDB_URL);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(
    process.env.DB_NAME,
    process.env.DB_USER,
    process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    {
      dialect: 'mysql',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3306
    }
  );
} 

module.exports = sequelize;
```

```
 The server.js file is:
```

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const routes = require("./routes");
const sequelize = require("./config/connection");

const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var corsOptions = {
  //for online use
  // origin: "https://operations-limit-database.herokuapp.com"
  //first trying this without credentials to see how it works
  // credentials: true,

  //for local use
  origin: "http://localhost:3000"
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

// parse requests of content-type - application/json
app.use(express.json());
// parse requests of content-type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// turn on routes
app.use(routes);
// simple route


//the below two are for deployed builds
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build')));
}

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build/index.html'));
});

//this is for local build only
// app.get("/", (req, res) => {
//   res.json({ message: "Welcome to Homeschool's Op Limit Database" });
// });

// turn on connection to db and server
//{ force: false } to drop tables and recreate
sequelize.sync().then(() => {
  app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`));
});
```

```
 And the .env file looks like below:
```

```
DB_NAME= 'xxxx'
DB_USER= 'yyyy'
DB_PASSWORD= 'zzzz'
DB_SECRET='aaaa'
```

Not sure what I.m missing, it was up and running over the weekend and then just stopped.  Anything i can try would be appreciated.

So far i've tried reordering the .env, changing databases, and rebuilding the app, all to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you dont pass dialect to sequelize properly, make sure that you are passing the string and the environment variables are getting passed, usually it is the case.

```js
const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
  dialect: 'mysql',
  dialectOptions: {
    // Your mysql2 options here
  }
})
```

[Documentation](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/dialect-specific-things/)

Comment: Manoj, I beleive i'm passing the string variables correctly with my .env file and i am passing the dialect directly:   ```sequelize = new Sequelize(
    process.env.DB_NAME,
    process.env.DB_USER,
    process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    {
      dialect: 'mysql',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3306
    }
  );```